# How to change class of elements in adjacent rows of HTML table using jQuery's nextAll() selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I tried to change class using `.nextAll(':lt(3)')` jQuery selector I ran into a problem.

Class doesn't change in new rows of html tables. If I understand correctly, class change of next 3 cells are applied by this method.

Is there any method to fix it?

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $('td').removeClass('outpatient'); //If you want to reset in each click
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('outpatient');
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outpatient {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) for `.nextAll()`

> Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector

Since the next row is not a sibling of `td` element you have to target the next row separately. To do this you can count how many elements were selected by `.nextAll()` and color the rest of the required elements in the next row.

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $('td').removeClass('outpatient'); //If you want to reset in each click
    $(this).nextAll(':lt(3)').addClass('outpatient');
    
    fromNextRow = 3 - $(this).nextAll(':lt(3)').length;
    $(this).parent().next().children(':lt('+ fromNextRow +')').addClass('outpatient');
  });
});
```

```css
table td {
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.outpatient {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tr>
</table>
```